# Iterate over dataframe and create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column that takes the result from another column and gets the index value from a list. I've tried using itertuples which rather than gets the correct index, always gets the last index. I've also tried creating a column but it says the truth value of a series is ambiguous. The datasets could be large so efficiency is important.

```
import pandas as pd

Year = [2020,2021,2022]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2020,,2021,2021,2022],'Sales':[100000,101000,103000,112000]})
```

##This ends up setting the index for all years as 2 rather than giving them their respective index

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    value = getattr(row, 'Year')
    df['Index_value'] = Year.index((value)
print(df)
```

##This returns an error that the truth value of a series is ambiguous.

```
df['Index_value'] = Year.index(df['Year'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` method to apply a certain function to each row, for example:

```
Year = [2020,2021,2022]

def get_index(year):
    return Year.index(year)

df['Index_value'] = df['Year'].apply(get_index)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Year   Sales  Index_value
0  2020  100000            0
1  2021  101000            1
2  2021  103000            1
3  2022  112000            2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a dataframe from the `Year` list and merging it with your original dataframe:

```py
Year = [2020,2021,2022]

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Year':[2020,2021,2021,2022],
  'Sales':[100000,101000,103000,112000]}
)
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(Year, columns=['Year']).reset_index(names='Index_value'))
```

Output:

```
   Year   Sales  Index_value
0  2020  100000            0
1  2021  101000            1
2  2021  103000            1
3  2022  112000            2
```

Alternatively you could build a map from the `Year` list and apply that to the `Year` column:

```py
ymap = { Year[i] : i for i in range(len(Year)) }
df['Index_value'] = df['Year'].map(ymap)
```

The output is the same as the above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate, just [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values from a dictionary:

```
df['Index_value'] = df['Year'].map({y: i for i,y in enumerate(Year)})
```

Or:

```
df['Index_value'] = df['Year'].map(dict(zip(Year, range(len(Year)))))
```

Output:

```
   Year   Sales  Index_value
0  2020  100000            0
1  2021  101000            1
2  2021  103000            1
3  2022  112000            2
```

Intermediate dictionary:

```
{2020: 0, 2021: 1, 2022: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One code line is enough to get your expected result.

```
df['Index_value'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: Year.index(x))
```

Output

```
   Year   Sales  Index_value
0  2020  100000            0
1  2021  101000            1
2  2021  103000            1
3  2022  112000            2
```